# jQuery play audio by selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-audio

I have 2 audio tags and a button
When I click the button, if it's true I want to play sound1 and if it's not I want to play sound2

```
<button>play</button>

<audio class="sound1" src="sound1.mp3" ></audio>
<audio class="sound2" src="sound2.mp3" ></audio>
```

jQuery:

```
$('button').click(function() {
  if (true) {
    audio.play();
  } else {

  }
});
```

I don't know how to get the audio object by a class name

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("sound1")[0];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `.play()` to trigger the audio, and use `$(selector).get(0)` to get the audio object.

```
$('button').click(function(){
  if ( true ) {
    $('.sound1').get(0).play();
  } else {
    $('.sound2').get(0).play();
  }
});
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/aL6bemfo/) (Toggle `true / false` to hear `.wav` and `.mp3` file)

<sup>[Audio Credits](https://hpr.dogphilosophy.net/test/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

the better way is to set the src of your audio according to your condition something like

```
$('button').click(function(){
// Select the sourceUrl according to your selection then set the source to your audio control
$('.sound').attr('src', sourceUrl);
}
```